# How to use two 'for each' loops simultaneously

Tags: excel, vba, loops, foreach

So, I have an assignment that requires me to select some rows from TWO databases (in .xlsx format) if (and only if) the value of an element in either database (for example, 57 in database1 or 38 in database2) EXISTS in BOTH databases. So, I've thought of making two for each... next loops, as

```
for each x in database1 'and below 
    for each y in database2
        if x=y then '(then I proceed to copy the row in which the x (or y) is located, I figured out a way to do this, this isn't the problem) 
        Else
        End if 
    Next
Next
```

Unfortunately, what I did only allows one of the two variables (in this case `y`) to loop, and `x` stays in a constant cell.

I'd like to know if there's a solution to this, I want to loop through two lists simultaneously, I've read a question, but the solution is meant for another programming language.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order to most effectively help you with your question, can you please post the code you have tried so far?

Comment: `and x stays in a constant cell` - no, it does not. It loops as well, producing [nested loops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_loop_join).

Answer (score 0):

I dont see why wouldn't this work.

It will iterate over all `y` and compare to first element of `x`, then 2nd element of `x` with all `y` and so on.

Add a `continue` statement in your `if` and remove `else` if not needed.